# Всплывающее окно заблокировано

Tags: opera, всплывающее-окно

При создании окна функцией **`window.open`**, во всех браузерах всё нормально, но вот в опере предупреждение: "**Всплывающее окно заблокировано.**"

```
function _test() {
 run_task = window.open(url, 'run_task', 'width=860, height=500, resizable=yes');
}
```

Comment: В опере всплывающим считается окно, которое открывается не по инициативе пользователя (скажем из `onload`). На клик должно открываться.

Comment: Покопайте lostfilm.tv. Там тоже всплывающие окна, но всё работает.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, блокирует также.

Comment: Никак, такая защита есть, по моему, в каждом браузере. И прежде чем открыть окно, браузер его сначала блокирует и спрашивает разрешения. Используйте модальые окна.

Comment: @lampa, у меня открывается окно с ссылкой на vk. А если использовать модальные окна, то придётся пихать в них iframe="vk.com/...". А у ВК стоит защита. То есть фрейм на их сайт не сделать.

Comment: У вас стоит настройка "блокировать незапрашиваемые" в опере? Это стандартная настройка и с ней на лостфильме всё грузится, также грузятся все окна авторизации контактовские, гугловские.

Comment: @ReklatsMasters, стоит. Но я не ставил.

Comment: @lampa, @ReklatsMasters, сделаю вообщем проверку, если отключены, то.. И ещё, обычно у всех разрешено открывать всплывающие окна или же у всех запрещено в настройках?

Comment: Я у себя запрещаю, надеюсь, что другие будут поступать так же (правда я и js поотключал бы везде, но есть некоторые сайты, которые хочу смотреть). Поэтому ищите способы работать не надеясь на ослабленные параметры безопасности.

Comment: @alexlz: наверное, [вот это](http://noscript.net/) как раз для вас

Comment: @VladD спасибо, но уже установлен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если в настройках Оперы или любого другого браузера выставить блокировку всплывающих окон - то тут ничего не сделаешь, будет спрашивать или молча блокировать (смотря что юзер в настройках выберет).
 А вот если настройки браузера по-умолчанию, то вызов window.open не блокируется, при условии что он стоит первым в стеке вызовов ф-ций. Т.е. если вы в какой-то ф-ции которая выполняется в реалтайме вызовите window.open - то она отработает без блокировок, а если будете вызывать window.open из колбека ajax-запроса или из setInterval, setTimeout - то будет происходить блокировка